# How to find LDAP details on Windows 7

Tags: ldap

I have a Windows 7 workstation connected to an Active Directory and everything works find.

But what I need to do is to find out the connection details. I found that the AD server is "ad.localnetwork.local", listening on port 389, but I don't know how to find the "dn" (domain name), the "ou" (organizational unit).

Would someone happened to know where we can get this info on Windows 7?

Thanks

Comment: Check out [LDAP: The RootDSE](http://ldapmaven.com/2011/04/11/the-root-dse-is-that-entry-with-zero-rdns-and-contains-information-about-the-directory-server/).

Answer (score 0):

Root DSE should be able to give you information about naming contexts and other directory relevant information.

```
ldapsearch -b " " -s base objectclass=*

LDAP://rootDSE
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/microsoft-active-directory/9780596156305/searching-and-manipulating-objects/viewing_the_rootdse